# Postgresql: Insert with returnig incremental id

Tags: sql, postgresql

With Postgresql i can INSERT with a returning result, eg.:

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname) VALUES ('Joe', 'Cool') RETURNING id;
```

output

```
| id |
------
|  1 |
```

but, i have a table with only a incremental ID. If I want insert new ID and return the inserted value, with this sinxax don't works:

```
INSERT INTO my_ids RETURNING id;
```

output

```
Invalid sintax near RETURNING
```

hof fix?

Comment: Maybe you need [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)?

Comment: Also look for HiLo term.

Comment: `INSERT INTO my_ids(id) values(default) RETURNING id;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thaks, works!